# Conversion of energy to matter or antimatter?

Tags: soft-question, mass-energy, antimatter

1. We all know that matter converts into energy, but will energy convert into matter?
2. Does it form antimatter by converting? Illustrate me with example.

Comment: The first question is a duplicate of [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16777/).

Comment: Also a duplicate of [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146796/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes energy will convert into matter, this happens in particle accelerators a high amount of energy is pumped into a particle and then when it collides with another one, it will form new particles from the energy. Antimatter can also be formed in these high energy collisions such as when a muon is created and after about 2 micro seconds the muon decays into an electron, a muon neutrino and a muon anti-neutrino

Comment: But when the muon is formed, is an anti-muon formed as well?

Comment: @JoshuaLin: the short answer is yes. The longer answer is that any reaction which doesn't break the conservation laws for the force involved is allowed. The major laws involved in $\gamma \to \mu\bar{\mu}$ are conservation of lepton number and electric charge (although energy, momentum etc have a role as well).

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the pair production describes that energy can be converted into both mater and antimatter through photon over or equal to a threshold of 1.02 MeV. Since Albert Einstein’s infamous equation, E = mc^2 tells us that matter and energy is interchangeable so if matter can become energy, then energy can become matter. I am actually doing a research project based on this, although I would need a lab to experiment on this idea.